# Check if JSON as dictionary contains Optional(null)

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I want to make an if statement that checks if my JSON (item_section) has a null value at a certain key.

This code:

```
let my_dict = item_section[counter].dictionaryValue
print(my_dict["creator"])
```

prints: `Optional(null)` when the creator is not set.

If it is set if it prints the creator's name, like: `user_729834892`.

How can I make an if statement that checks if the creator is null?

Such as:

```
if ((my_dict["creator"]) == nil) {  //This line does not work
    my_dict["creator"] = "No Maker"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if my_dict["creator"].type == .Null {
    print("creator is null")
}
```

Comment: Or you can compare directly with `JSON.null`.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` framework never returns an optional when indexing a dictionary (a JSON object). If the value doesn't exist, it rather returns the constant `JSON.null`, which you can compare:

```
if my_dict["creator"] == JSON.null {
    my_dict["creator"] = "No Maker"
}
```

also method `isExists` would work

```
if !my_dict["creator"].isExists() {
    my_dict["creator"] = "No Maker"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    print( my_dict.indexForKey( "creator") )

    if (my_dict.indexForKey( "creator") == nil) {

        my_dict["creator"] = "No Maker"
    }
```

if the creator is not set then function indexForKey will return nil.